# Split multiple class with same name using loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multiple tag in my webpage with the same class called price. Each tag is of that form

```
<p class="price">Price: 45$</p>
<p class="price">Price: 32$</p>
```

What I need at the end is to separate the price text in a span and the price in another so that it will be like that

```
<p class="price"><span class='h1'>Price:</span> <span class="h2">45$</span></p>
```

This is what I do until now but problem is that the span is not a tag but is insert as a simple string

[image]

```
let price = $(".price");
for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    let priceTitle = price[i].innerText.split(":")[0];
    let priceToPay = price[i].innerText.split(":")[1];
    price[i].innerText = ''; //Delete content of price
    

    $(".price")[i].append("<span class='h1'>"+ priceTitle+"</span> <span class='h2'>"+ priceToPay +"</span>");

}

}
```

Can you help me fix this issue and perhaps optimize the code I already do.

Comment: There is no such thing as `some errors`. Each error has a message that you should read and include here if you are asking

Comment: this wont fix ur issue (idk what issue r u having, share the errors), but u don't need to split the same thing 2 times, u can do the following `let splitted = myString.split(':'); let one = splitted[0]; let two = splitted[1]`, etc

Comment: You are trying to use a variable that doesn't exist

Comment: @ericmp See edit. Problem is that insert the span as a string and not as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just a few syntax errors e.g. you've set priceToPay then used price_toPay in your final line of code. Also jQuery.append() method is setting your content as textContent and not HTML but just use innerHTML instead.  I've added a button for you to click so you can see the before and after effects.  See below

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', doFormat);
}

function doFormat() {
  let price = $(".price");
  for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    const priceTextContentArray = price[i].innerText.split(":");
    let priceTitle = priceTextContentArray[0];
    let priceToPay = priceTextContentArray[1];

    price[i].innerHTML =
      "<span class='h1'>" +
      priceTitle +
      "</span> <span class='h2'>" +
      priceToPay +
      "</span>";
  }
}
```

```css
.h1 {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.h2 {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" defer></script>

<button id='mybutton'>Format</button><br>


<p class="price">Price: 45$</p>
<p class="price">Price: 32$</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "the jQuery way", to build elements from strings you must use the `$` constructor:

replace:

```
price[i].innerText = ''; //Delete content of price
$(".price")[i].append("<span class='h1'>"+ priceTitle+"</span> <span class='h2'>"+ priceToPay +"</span>");
```

by:

```
$(price[i]).html('').append( $("<span class='h1'>"+ priceTitle +"</span> <span class='h2'>"+ priceToPay +"</span>") );
```

As you see in jQuery you can also chain the calls, and use the `.html()` or `.text()` dedicated functions. `html` is more suitable here as you want to delete all inside your element, not just the text part

Notice that I also corrected your `$(".price")[i]` to `$(price[i])`, it is safer to use the var you loop on instead of doing a new jQuery selection and assume it will have the same index as in your loop